# Building Web app with existing cpp core code

Tags: c++

I have an Android/iPhone apps that share the same cpp core engine.
I want to use the same cpp core engine in the web app in some way.

I wonder what are my options? What is the best approach?

Comment: Wasn't the android SDK in Java? Can you really build android apps in C++?

Comment: Sure you can. Just check this out: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: yep. I use JNI to communicate between the JAVA UI code and the CPP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to re-use the existing C++ code, then depending on your platform you can write a CGI (Common Gateway Interface) extension for your favourite web-server.

If your platform is Windows, you can also write an ISAPI extension DLL in C++ and access your core library from there.